# How to close redis pool connections for dynamically created celery instance

Tags: python, sockets, redis, celery

After updating redis cluster I started getting max connections error from redis server, to fix this I set inactive connection timeout (https://redis.io/topics/clients here it stated with newer versions it now defaults to not have this timeout). This fixed the issue however after a few days celery could not make new connections because the sockets were clogged up with old connections in `CLOSE_WAIT` state. I've tried doing `celery.close()` and `celery.backend.client.connection_pool.disconnect()` at the end of these celery instance life cycle but both seem to have no effect on the amount of redis connections open.

I also tried refactoring my app to singleton celery approach - to do this I had to use thread lock on functions that called celery tasks synchronously `send_task(..).get()` to avoid concurrent redis pool calls, which is the reason it was made with dynamic celery instances in the first place, however with this approach I got `wrong number of arguments for 'subscribe' command` error occasionally only on production, that I couldnt find any info on.

Im using celery 4.4.7, python redis client 3.2.0 and redis engine version is 5.0.6
Any ideas appreciated.